# ORDER BY with Inner query, giving ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to test a query and getting the `ORA-00907` error. I believe that the error is due to the inner query I am using for `RUN.RN_RUN_ID`.
 The inner query by itself works fine and I give the result of the inner query, the outer query is working fine. Any insight into what I am doing wrong, would be much appreciated.

```
Select
    RELEASES.REL_NAME AS RELEASE_NAME,
    RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_NAME AS CYCLE_NAME,
    TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID AS TEST_INSTANCE_ID,
    TEST.TS_NAME AS TEST_CASE_NAME,
    TEST.TS_USER_26 AS TEST_POST_CONDITIONS,
    TEST.TS_USER_25 AS TEST_PRE_CONDITIONS,
    TEST.TS_TEST_ID AS TEST_CASE_ID,
    TEST.TS_DESCRIPTION AS TEST_CASE_DESCRIPTION,
    TESTCYCL.TC_STATUS  AS TEST_ACTUAL_RESULTS,
    TEST.TS_DEV_COMMENTS AS TEST_CASE_COMMENTS,
    TEST.TS_RESPONSIBLE AS TEST_CASE_AUTHOR,
    TEST.TS_CREATION_DATE AS TEST_CASE_CREATION_DATE,
    TESTCYCL.TC_EXEC_DATE AS EXECUTION_DATE,
    TESTCYCL.TC_EXEC_TIME AS EXECUTION_TIME,
    TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER AS EXECUTED_BY,
    STEP.ST_ID AS STEP_ID,
    STEP.ST_STEP_NAME AS STEP_NUMBER,
    STEP.ST_DESCRIPTION AS STEP_DESCRIPTION,
    STEP.ST_EXPECTED AS EXPECTED_RESULTS,
    STEP.ST_ACTUAL AS ACTUAL_RESULTS,
    STEP.ST_USER_07 AS STEP_COMMENT,
    STEP.ST_STATUS AS STEP_STATUS,
    STEP.ST_STEP_ORDER AS STEP_ORDER,
    STEP.ST_USER_01 AS STEP_TYPE,
    RUN.RN_RUN_ID AS RUN_ID From ((((((RELEASES JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES
    ON RELEASES.REL_ID = RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_PARENT_ID 
    AND RELEASES.REL_NAME = 'XYZ') LEFT JOIN CYCLE
    ON RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_ID = CYCLE.CY_ASSIGN_RCYC) LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL
    ON CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID = TESTCYCL.TC_CYCLE_ID) LEFT JOIN RUN
    ON TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID = RUN.RN_TESTCYCL_ID) LEFT JOIN TEST
    ON TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID = TEST.TS_TEST_ID) LEFT JOIN STEP
    ON RUN.RN_RUN_ID = STEP.ST_RUN_ID) WHERE (TEST.TS_TYPE = 'MANUAL' OR 
    TEST.TS_TYPE  = 'QUICKTEST_TEST' OR TEST.TS_TYPE = 'LR-SCENARIO')
    AND RUN.RN_RUN_ID in(Select max(RUN.RN_RUN_ID) From (((((((RELEASES JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES
    ON  RELEASES.REL_ID = RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_PARENT_ID AND RELEASES.REL_NAME = 'XYZ') 
    LEFT JOIN  CYCLE ON RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_ID = CYCLE.CY_ASSIGN_RCYC)
    LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL ON CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID = TESTCYCL.TC_CYCLE_ID)
    LEFT JOIN RUN ON TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID = RUN.RN_TESTCYCL_ID)
    LEFT JOIN TEST ON TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID = TEST.TS_TEST_ID)
    LEFT JOIN STEP ON RUN.RN_RUN_ID = STEP.ST_RUN_ID)
    LEFT JOIN LINK ON STEP.ST_ID  = LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID AND LINK.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'STEP')
    WHERE (TEST.TS_TYPE = 'MANUAL' OR TEST.TS_TYPE = 'QUICKTEST_TEST' OR 
    TEST.TS_TYPE = 'LR-SCENARIO')AND TEST.TS_TEST_ID =145965
    ORDER BY TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID)
    ORDER BY TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID,STEP.ST_STEP_ORDER
```

Comment: Too many left parenthesis!! near `(((((((RELEASES`

Comment: Add a closing bracket.

Comment: We are not human compilers.  strip down your query and add back pieces incrementally.

Comment: I always try to avoid those brackets for joins that were mainly generated by query designer programs. The sqls are quick becoming unmaintainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coding style and unnecessary nested brackets make this really hard to read and interpret. But it also does help that, contrary to some comments, an ORA-00907 doesn't always mean an uneven number of parentheses, it can indicate a more general syntax error that's caused the parser to bail out. In this case it isn't very helpful.

The problem is the `order by` clause on the penultimate line, within the subquery you're comparing against with `in`:

```
...
AND RUN.RN_RUN_ID in(Select max(RUN.RN_RUN_ID) From (((((((RELEASES JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES
...
TEST.TS_TYPE = 'LR-SCENARIO')AND TEST.TS_TEST_ID =145965
ORDER BY TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID)
ORDER BY TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID,STEP.ST_STEP_ORDER
```

The final ordering is obviously allowed, but in that subquery it is not. So it should end:

```
...
TEST.TS_TYPE = 'LR-SCENARIO')AND TEST.TS_TEST_ID =145965)
ORDER BY TESTCYCL.TC_TESTCYCL_ID,STEP.ST_STEP_ORDER
```

I can't test that as I don't have your schema, but a simpler demo might help demonstrate:

```
select d1.dummy
from dual d1
where d1.dummy in (
  select dummy
  from dual d2
  order by d2.dummy
)
order by d1.dummy;

Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 3
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

Removing the inner `order by`:

```
select d1.dummy
from dual d1
where d1.dummy in (
  select dummy
  from dual d2
)
order by d1.dummy;

DUMMY
-----
X
```

It is expecting to see a `)` instead of that `order by`, so the error does make some sense, once you know what it wrong; but it doesn't really help you narrow it down.

Incidentally, this is referenced in Oracle support document 731577.1:

> Getting `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` when using an `ORDER BY` clause in a subquery.  When the `ORDER BY` clause is removed the query runs without error.
>
> ...
>   This is expected behavior per Bug 4944718
>   `ORDER BY` in a subquery shouldn't work, since the order of the rows is  passed to the outer query and has no impact.

It is allowed/ignored in an inline view, but not in a nested subquery. (Though there may be exceptions where it still doesn't throw an error...)

Comment: Thanks Alex . I removed the inner order by and it is working fine.