# Oracle query failed: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle

I have this query executed on **ORACLE SGBD**

```
update product p set p.PROVIDER_ID = 
( select PROVIDER_ID from provider pr where pr.VALID_FROM is not null 
 and ((pr.VALID_TO is not null and pr.VALID_TO < p.VALID_TO ) 
 or (pr.VALID_TO is  null and pr.VALID_FROM < p.VALID_TO) )
 and rownum < 2 order by valid_to desc 
)
 where p.VALID_FROM is not null and p.VALID_TO is not null;
```

Executing this query I get this error:

```
  [UPDATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 907, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.
```

I'm blocked at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21859866/266304), as the immediate problem is that you have an `order by` clause in a subquery - that isn't allowed and is causing this error. Oracle is expecting to see the closing parenthesis of the subquery after the `rownum < 2`.

But in this case it's slightly more complicated because you need the order by to get the desired row to match against, and you've got the `rownum` check in the wrong place; even as a standalone query that wouldn't give you the result you expect as it would find one indeterminate row and then order that single row, which is meaningless.

You need another layer, so your subquery has an inline view which can be ordered, and then you get the first row from that:

```
update product p set p.PROVIDER_ID = 
(
  select PROVIDER_ID from (
    select pr.PROVIDER_ID from provider pr
    where pr.VALID_FROM is not null 
    and ((pr.VALID_TO is not null and pr.VALID_TO < p.VALID_TO) 
      or (pr.VALID_TO is null and pr.VALID_FROM < p.VALID_TO))
    order by pr.VALID_TO desc
  )
  where rownum < 2
)
where p.VALID_FROM is not null and p.VALID_TO is not null;
```

But now you'll get `ORA-00904: "P"."VALID_TO": invalid identifier` because you're trying to correlate the update by referencing columns from the `p` alias two levels down, which Oracle doesn't allow.

An alternative is to use analytics, such as `keep dense_rank`:

```
update product p set p.PROVIDER_ID = 
(
  select max(pr.PROVIDER_ID) keep (dense_rank first order by pr.VALID_TO desc)
  from provider pr
  where pr.VALID_FROM is not null 
  and ((pr.VALID_TO is not null and pr.VALID_TO < p.VALID_TO) 
    or (pr.VALID_TO is null and pr.VALID_FROM < p.VALID_TO))
)
where p.VALID_FROM is not null and p.VALID_TO is not null;
```

... which does run successfully. (I'm not entirely sure about your date comparison logic but that's a separate issue, and may actually be what you want).