# Sql - "missing right parenthesis" error explanation

Tags: sql, oracle

My code is syntactically correct and I don't think that I need any parenthesis, 
however it keeps coming up with an error "00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"" without any explanation of the cause

```
SELECT DISTINCT BG.name 
FROM Brand_Group BG
WHERE BG.pid=(SELECT P.pid 
  FROM Indicia_Publisher IP
  LEFT JOIN Publisher P ON IP.pid=P.pid
  WHERE (IP.cid=(SELECT Country.cid 
                FROM Country 
                WHERE Country.name='Belgium') AND ROWNUM<=1)
  GROUP BY P.pid
  ORDER BY COUNT(P.pid));
```

Comment: ROWNUM is oracle syntax not mysql.. i've removed the mysql tag

Comment: What should `ORDER BY COUNT(P.pid)` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORDER BY with Inner query, giving ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859866/order-by-with-inner-query-giving-ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is to do with the `ORDER BY` in the comparison subquery - it's not valid syntax, which you can see by running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE dummy IN (SELECT dummy FROM dual ORDER BY dummy);
```

Remove the `ORDER BY` clause and your query should run without issue.

Also, if you're wanting to get distinct rows returned and you're not using an aggregate function (e.g. MAX, SUM, etc), then you should use DISTINCT, not GROUP BY - it makes your intention much clearer. However, since you've restricted the results to a single row with `and rownum = 1`, there's not much point in using either!

Your query should probably be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bg.name
FROM   brand_group bg
WHERE  bg.pid = (SELECT p.pid
                 FROM   indicia_publisher ip
                 LEFT   JOIN publisher p
                 ON     ip.pid = p.pid
                 WHERE  ip.cid = (SELECT country.cid
                                  FROM   country
                                  WHERE  country.name = 'Belgium') AND rownum <= 1);
```

---

ETA: I see that I misread your original SQL slightly and misinterpreted what you were after. It looks like you're after the p.pids with the highest count, so the following should do what you're after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bg.name
FROM   brand_group bg
WHERE  bg.pid = (SELECT p.pid
                 FROM   (SELECT p.pid,
                                COUNT(*) cnt,
                                MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY p.id) max_cnt
                         FROM   indicia_publisher ip
                         LEFT   JOIN publisher p
                         ON     ip.pid = p.pid
                         WHERE  ip.cid = (SELECT country.cid
                                          FROM   country
                                          WHERE  country.name = 'Belgium')
                         GROUP BY p.pid)
                 WHERE  cnt = max_cnt
                 AND    ROWNUM = 1);
```

If there are two or more different p.pids that have the highest count, the `and rownum = 1` ensures only one will be picked (but it'll be random). May you want to use `IN` rather than `=` in the outer query's comparison, and that would remove the need for the `rownum = 1` predicate.

Answer (score -2):

is this Oracle, SQL Server? Oracle does not use left, Sql server does not have rownum. Do you expect one or more value to be return in subquery. it looks like more than 1. Then change BG.cid = () to ip.cid in (). Do you need the group in that subquery. You don't have count in that subquery.

I suggest you execute subquery one by one to find out what happens

Your original one has mixed of syntax (oracle/SqL server). I am going assume this is Oracle database

```
SELECT DISTINCT BG.name 
FROM Brand_Group BG
WHERE BG.pid in 
    (SELECT P.pid 
    FROM Indicia_Publisher IP
    WHERE 
    IP.pid=P.pid (+) and
    (IP.cid=(SELECT Country.cid 
            FROM Country 
            WHERE Country.name='Belgium') AND ROWNUM<=1)    
    );
```

Comment: "Oracle does not use left", are you sure? Also, are you sure this query runs?

Comment: Oracle has used ANSI join syntax since version 9i, so I'm not sure why you think it can't handle LEFT OUTER JOINs!