# Order BY in Subquery : Missing right parenthese

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to update 2 columns using a subquery with a specific order so the query is like that:

```
UPDATE myTable TAO
  SET (TAO.BASE_AMT,TAO.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) = (SELECT SUM(decode(TAX_CD_VAT_PCT,0,0,d.monetary_amount))
                                                , MAX (D.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT)
                                           FROM source1 w
                                              , source2 d
                                           WHERE 1=1
                                           -- Some conditions
                                            GROUP BY d.business_unit, d.voucher_id
                                            ORDER BY d.business_unit, d.voucher_id);
```

Why am I getting:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

**EDIT 1**

the query with all conditions :

```
UPDATE myTable TAO 
  SET (TAO.BASE_AMT,TAO.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) = ( 
 SELECT SUM(decode(TAX_CD_VAT_PCT 
 , 0 
 , 0 
 ,d.monetary_amount)) 
 , MAX (D.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) 
  FROM source1 w 
  , source2 d 
 WHERE w.business_unit = TAO.BUSINESS_UNIT 
   AND d.business_unit = w.business_unit 
   AND d.voucher_id = w.voucher_id 
   AND d.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = w.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM 
   AND d.VOUCHER_ID = TAO.VOUCHER_ID 
  GROUP BY d.business_unit, d.voucher_id
  ORDER BY d.business_unit, d.voucher_id )
```

Comment: @lucumt i didn't understand exactly your question..
but i removed the order by and the query worked

Comment: What is the point of seeing an order on an update query?

Comment: If you remove the order by, the update works?? I don't think the update can be done like that, associating several columns in only one SET statement. And, like @LJ01 wrote, i don't see logic in ordering to perform an update.

Comment: @LJ01 you mean the order by isn't necessary and will not impact the result ?

Comment: No join condition?

Comment: I would have imagined the order by had no impact on the update query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORDER BY with Inner query, giving ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859866/order-by-with-inner-query-giving-ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis)

Comment: @LJ01 I said the same thing but i'm not sure at 100 %

Comment: `ORDER BY` in a sub-query makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso: `set (a,b) = (select x,y ...)` is perfectly valid as long as the sub-select only returns a single row.

Comment: please check the EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would appear to want a correlated subquery, because your subquery can return multiple rows.

You don't provide a table layout, but I would expect:

```
UPDATE myTable TAO
  SET (BASE_AMT, TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) =
          (SELECT SUM(d.monetary_amount),  -- the DECODE does nothing
                  MAX(D.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT)
           FROM source1 w JOIN  -- ALWAYS use proper, explicit, standard JOIN syntax
                source2 d
                ON . . . 
           WHERE . . . AND
                 d.business_unit = TAO.business_unit AND
                 d.voucher_id = TAO.voucher_id
          );
```

Your code is filled with anachronisms and bad practices:

- The `DECODE()` does nothing.  If it did, you should use `CASE` expressions instead.
- Commas in `JOIN` clauses have been obsolete for over fifteen years.  Use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.
- The `ORDER BY` in the subquery does nothing.

Comment: Yes finnaly i am convinced that the order by isn't usefull, can you check the edit please ?
i think i should use the group by

Answer (score 0):

Subquery have group by clause which can return multiple rows. 
Update query cannot take list of values to update.

So, for every unique combination of `d.business_unit, d.voucher_id`, there will be one row even if you did not select those columns in the inner query.

Also, assuming it returns only one row, you are missing where clause for update query. Only where clause I can see is in subquery.